# undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::zlib::deflated'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

I am trying to install the [Trans-Proteomic Pipeline found here](http://tools.proteomecenter.org/software.php). I have installed each of the necessary libraries mentioned in the readme, but when I run `make all` or `make install` it progresses through much of the compilation, and then errors out with the following message:

```
undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::zlib::deflated'
```

The error log is much longer with what seems to be redundant information but it generally looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/nkho/proj/tpp/release_6-0-0/build/gnu-x86_64-rc28/lib/libpwiz.a(MSDataFile.o): in function `pwiz::msdata::(anonymous namespace)::openFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)':
MSDataFile.cpp:(.text+0x1cda): undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::zlib::deflated'
/usr/bin/ld: MSDataFile.cpp:(.text+0x1cf8): undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::zlib::default_strategy'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/nkho/proj/tpp/release_6-0-0/build/gnu-x86_64-rc28/lib/libpwiz.a(MSDataFile.o): in function `boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_compressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::impl>::dispose()':
MSDataFile.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6detail17sp_counted_impl_pINS_9iostreams16symmetric_filterINS2_6detail20zlib_compressor_implISaIcEEES6_E4implEE7disposeEv[_ZN5boost6detail17sp_counted_impl_pINS_9iostreams16symmetric_filterINS2_6detail20zlib_compressor_implISaIcEEES6_E4implEE7disposeEv]+0x27): undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::reset(bool, bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: MSDataFile.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6detail17sp_counted_impl_pINS_9iostreams16symmetric_filterINS2_6detail20zlib_compressor_implISaIcEEES6_E4implEE7disposeEv[_ZN5boost6detail17sp_counted_impl_pINS_9iostreams16symmetric_filterINS2_6detail20zlib_compressor_implISaIcEEES6_E4implEE7disposeEv]+0x2f): undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::~zlib_base()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/nkho/proj/tpp/release_6-0-0/build/gnu-x86_64-rc28/lib/libpwiz.a(MSDataFile.o): in function `boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_compressor<std::allocator<char> >::basic_gzip_compressor(boost::iostreams::gzip_params const&, int)':
MSDataFile.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9iostreams21basic_gzip_compressorISaIcEEC2ERKNS0_11gzip_paramsEi[_ZN5boost9iostreams21basic_gzip_compressorISaIcEEC5ERKNS0_11gzip_paramsEi]+0x1d7): undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::zlib_base()'
/usr/bin/ld: MSDataFile.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9iostreams21basic_gzip_compressorISaIcEEC2ERKNS0_11gzip_paramsEi[_ZN5boost9iostreams21basic_gzip_compressorISaIcEEC5ERKNS0_11gzip_paramsEi]+0x1f9): undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::do_init(boost::iostreams::zlib_params const&, bool, void* (*)(void*, unsigned int, unsigned int), void (*)(void*, void*), void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: MSDataFile.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9iostreams21basic_gzip_compressorISaIcEEC2ERKNS0_11gzip_paramsEi[_ZN5boost9iostreams21basic_gzip_compressorISaIcEEC5ERKNS0_11gzip_paramsEi]+0x337): undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::zlib::best_compression'
/usr/bin/ld: MSDataFile.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9iostreams21basic_gzip_compressorISaIcEEC2ERKNS0_11gzip_paramsEi[_ZN5boost9iostreams21basic_gzip_compressorISaIcEEC5ERKNS0_11gzip_paramsEi]+0x34e): undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::zlib::best_speed'
/usr/bin/ld: MSDataFile.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9iostreams21basic_gzip_compressorISaIcEEC2ERKNS0_11gzip_paramsEi[_ZN5boost9iostreams21basic_gzip_compressorISaIcEEC5ERKNS0_11gzip_paramsEi]+0xa51): undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::reset(bool, bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: MSDataFile.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9iostreams21basic_gzip_compressorISaIcEEC2ERKNS0_11gzip_paramsEi[_ZN5boost9iostreams21basic_gzip_compressorISaIcEEC5ERKNS0_11gzip_paramsEi]+0xa59): undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::~zlib_base()'
/usr/bin/ld: MSDataFile.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9iostreams21basic_gzip_compressorISaIcEEC2ERKNS0_11gzip_paramsEi[_ZN5boost9iostreams21basic_gzip_compressorISaIcEEC5ERKNS0_11gzip_paramsEi]+0xa75): undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::reset(bool, bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: MSDataFile.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9iostreams21basic_gzip_compressorISaIcEEC2ERKNS0_11gzip_paramsEi[_ZN5boost9iostreams21basic_gzip_compressorISaIcEEC5ERKNS0_11gzip_paramsEi]+0xa7d): undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::~zlib_base()'
```

I've seen a variety of other questions with similar messages that mention one should define the path to the boost installation/binaries in the g++ command, but all I am running is `make install`, so I am not sure where I would specify this.

Comment: Is there a `configure` file where you can manually specify the boost library locations? Failing that, in the directory you run `make` there should be a file named `Makefile` which specifies the actual commands which are run, you might try manually modifying the arguments passed to the compiler in there

Comment: Hi @DominicPrice, thanks for your reply... There is no configure file. Here is the makefile: https://pastebin.com/MujjWkP9 ... I am not sure which line I would modify as I don't see any g++ commands :/

Comment: At the bottom it has `-include src/Makefile`, so it is including instructions from that makefile too

Comment: Btw did you do a system installation of boost? If not, try install it with something like `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` and see if that ‘just works’. If you do find the compiler args, then you need to add `-lboost_system` for it to use a system install. Also, inside the makefiles the compiler will often be referenced by a variable such as ${CC} rather than named directly. Sorry if I’m just telling you things you already know but I may be off to sleep now

Comment: I appreciate all info! I know very little about this so please don't hesitate to tell me everything :-). I tried installing `libboost-all-dev` as you recommended, and unfortunately it still didn't work. I got it to work finally after finding an install guide for version 5.2 (I'm using v6.0). Specifically here http://tools.proteomecenter.org/wiki/index.php?title=TPP_5.2.0:_Installing_on_Ubuntu_18.04_LTS ... There were several packages it said to install that were not included in the README the src files are shipped with. Anyways, it works now so I will accept an answer if you make one!

Comment: Congrats on getting it going :P but seeing as you managed to find the solution, I think it would be more helpful for others facing a similar issue if you made an answer briefly outlining what confused you and the resource which helped you!